# Create h:column components inside h:dataTable based on a list of column names

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I'm trying to create a `<h:dataTable>` using two lists. One list contains the column names and the other one contains the data that will populate the table. I need the list containing the column names because the data in the second one has more attributes than I'd like to display. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can if you use `<c:forEach>` to iterate over the column names and generate the `<h:column>` components necessary for `<h:dataTable>`. You can use the brace notation `[]` in EL to use the column name as a "dynamic" bean property name (or even as a `Map` key).

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.rows}" var="row">
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.columnNames}" var="columnName">
        <h:column>#{row[columnName]}</h:column>
    </c:forEach>
</h:dataTable>
```